# Why does ‘stty -echo’ not turn off the echo bit on macOS

Tags: macos, unix, stty

I am reading Understanding Unix/Linux Programming by Bruce Molay. In Chapter 5, the book introduces a new command `stty` which can help you configure your terminal setting.

One example mentioned in the book is to use `stty -echo` to turn off the echo, then I tried it on my Mac but found  it doesn't work at all.

```
// here is some infomation about my mac
Mac mini (M1, 2020)
OS version: 11.4

// by the way, I also tested it on my old intel mac, and I got the same result
Macbook Pro(Early 2015)
OS version: 10.15.6
```

```
// here are the commands I used in the terminal on Mac
➜  ~ stty -a # check the old 'echo bit' status
speed 38400 baud; 45 rows; 139 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
➜  ~ stty -echo # turn off echo bit
➜  ~ stty -a # see the results
speed 38400 baud; 45 rows; 139 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
```

Then I tested it in an **ubuntu** docker container, and `stty -echo` **worked perfectly**.

So why does it not work on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive shell retains some controls over stty setting.

In Ubuntu, you are using bash, whereas in MacOS, you are using zsh.

As a test, run /bin/bash in MacOS and do your test.

**Update**

Interactives shells do not effect stty's behavior, they can change tty's attributes equivalent of `stty echo`, just before displaying prompt.

You can verify this by running in zsh :

```
stty -a; stty -echo; stty -a
```

To ask zsh not to do `stty echo`, you can do :

```
unsetopt ZLE
```

But this disables zsh's editing capabilities, which is not what you want.

Comment: Hey Philippe, thanks for your great answer. I just switched the shell from zsh to bash on my Mac, and stty-echo turned off the echo bit successfully! So my current question is why different shells effect stty’s behavior and why zsh can not do this? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi Philippe, I just checked this question (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343088/what-is-the-equivalent-of-stty-echo-for-zsh) and the link to the mail discussion in the first answer. To be honest, I m still not clear about the issue:( , I am wondering is there anyway to make zsh’s behavior same as bash. Thanks again, Philippe:)